# py2neo: minimizing write-time when creating graph

Tags: neo4j, batch-processing, py2neo

I would write a huge graph to neo4j. Using my code would take slightly less than two months.

I took the data from [Kaggle's events recommendation challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/event-recommendation-engine-challenge/data), the `user_friends.csv` file I am using looks like

```
user,friends
3197468391,1346449342 3873244116 4226080662, ...
```

I used the py2neo `batch` facility to produce the code. Is it the best I can do or is there another way to significantly reduce the running time?

Here 's the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import division
from time import time
import sqlite3
from py2neo import neo4j

graph = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
batch = neo4j.WriteBatch(graph)

people = graph.get_or_create_index( neo4j.Node,"people")
friends = graph.get_or_create_index( neo4j.Relationship,"friends")

con = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = con.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT user, friends FROM user_friends LIMIT 2;") 

t=time()
for u_f in c:
    u_node = graph.get_or_create_indexed_node("people",'name',u_f[0]) 

    for f in u_f[1].split(" "):
        f_node = graph.get_or_create_indexed_node("people",'name', f)

        if not f_node.is_related_to(u_node, neo4j.Direction.BOTH,"friends"):
            batch.create((u_node,'friends',f_node))

    batch.submit()
print time()-t
```

Also I cannot find a way to create an undirected graph using the high level `py2neo` facilities? I know`cypher` can do this with someting like `create (node(1) -[:friends]-node(2))`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

YOu should create connections not with `Direction.BOTH`. Chose one direction, and then ignore using `Direction.BOTH` it when traversing - it has no performance impact but the relationship directions are then deterministic. Cypher does exactly that when you say `a--b`.